# Добавлять value при checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Постараюсь быть кратким.
В форме есть `hidden input` со стартовым значением. Так же есть 2 `checkbox input`, которые должны добавлять значение в атрибут `value` при `checked="true"` и убирать при `checked="false"`   ранее упомянутого `hidden input`. Пытаюсь реализовать на это jQuery, но уже второй час не могу сдвинуться с места.

Форма:

```
<div class="form-additionals">
    <label class="label">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox-hide" name="checkbox">
        <span class="fake-check"></span>
        <span class="checkbox-text">Чекбокс1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="label">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="checkbox-hide" name="checkbox2">
        <span class="fake-check"></span>
        <span class="checkbox-text">Чекбокс2</span>
    </label>
</div>
<input class="lv-input-goods" id="lv-formLanding1-goods" type="hidden" value="{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"}}" name="FormLanding[goods]" />
```

Скрипт, который есть на данный момент. Он для первого `checkbox`

```
$(function(){
 $('#checkbox').on('change', function(){
 if($('#checkbox').prop('checked')){
 $('#lv-formLanding1-goods').val('{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"},"offer_grunt":{"quantity":1,"sum":"220"}}');
 }else{
 $('#lv-formLanding1-goods').val('{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"}}');
 }
 });
});
```

При отправке формы значение `hidden input` не меняется. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Заранее огромное спасибо и + в карму!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё дело в экранировании поля `input`:

```js
    $(function(){
        $('#checkbox').on('change', function(){
            if($('#checkbox').prop('checked')){
                $('#lv-formLanding1-goods').val('{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"},"offer_grunt":{"quantity":1,"sum":"220"}}');
            }else{
                $('#lv-formLanding1-goods').val('{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"}}');
            }
            console.log($('#lv-formLanding1-goods').val());
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-additionals">
    <label class="label">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox-hide" name="checkbox">
        <span class="fake-check"></span>
        <span class="checkbox-text">Чекбокс1</span>
    </label>
    <label class="label">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="checkbox-hide" name="checkbox2">
        <span class="fake-check"></span>
        <span class="checkbox-text">Чекбокс2</span>
    </label>
</div>
<input class="lv-input-goods" id="lv-formLanding1-goods" type="hidden" value='{"offer_leather-china1":{"quantity":1,"sum":"260"}}' name="FormLanding[goods]" />
```